# Installation of Ultralytics and Yolov5 over Jetson Nano board (Jetpack 4.6.4).)

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson-nano

Device name - Jetson Nano
OS - 4.6.4
Python - 3.9

Objective - Install Ultralytics and run Yolo scripts - NVIDIA Jetson Nano Deployment - Ultralytics YOLOv8 Docs

Question - I have installed below dependencies as per the above mentioned article for ultralytics, now only pytorch and torchvision is remaining, that i have to install as per my hardware compatibility mentioned here - [https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson/72048](https://stackoverflow.com), i haven’t find anything that can relate case.

> pip list - pandas=1.1.4, pyyaml=5.3.1, pillow=10.1.0, pip=23.3.1,
> tqdm=4.64.0, matplotlib=3.3.0, numpy=1.26.2, psutil=5.9.6,
> opencv-python=4.6.0.66, requests=2.23.0, scipy=1.11.4,
> thop=0.1.1.post2207130030, seaborn=0.11.0.

As per this reference link ([https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson/72048](https://stackoverflow.com)) we only have PyTorch v1.10.0 for jetpack 4.6.4 and will only be supported for python 3.6, please help me to setup this.